# How to access a variable that its name is made up by various strings in Shell Script?

Tags: shell, parsing

So, this is similar to passing parameter by reference. I want to access a variable (echo) that its name is a combined string from different strings. A simple example would be the following:

```
A1=999
n="1"
B="A$n"
```

What I want is that when I do `echo $B`, it would return `999`. Please let me know if further explanation is required. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for indirection

```
echo ${!B}
```

From the bash manual

```
   ${!prefix*}
   ${!prefix@}
          Expands to the names of variables whose names begin with prefix,
          separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.
```

Comment: Hi Kevin, what if I do not use B and use "A$n" directly? It didn't work with "${!"A$n"}" as a variable I am trying to use.

Comment: Use B. There's no shortcut around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this

```
eval echo "$"$B
```

But Kevin's answer is definitely better.